# BorderLayout in java, button not moving

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

i've read about BorderLayout, and it appears that its added onto the .add clause for the object we want into a container. 
Unfortunately when i do this I fail to get the desired effect. 
My button has not moved. 
I havent used a JPanel, just buttons and the normal FlowLayout. 
While searching I found out that the books suggestion for BorderLayout.SOUTH was not the best way and that BorderLayout.PAGE_END is better.

So im wondering why my button isnt moving?

much appreciated guys.
thx

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class zx extends JFrame {
  public zx() {
    // create window
    super("title 2");
    setSize(100, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    //container
    Container area = getContentPane();

    //layout manager
    FlowLayout flowManager = new FlowLayout();
    area.setLayout(flowManager);

    //buttons
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    area.add(button1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    area.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    area.add(button3);

    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    area.add(button4);

    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    area.add(button5);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well... I guess you want `area` to have a `BorderLayout`, not a `FlowLayout`. You are setting it's layout to a `FlowLayout` at `FlowLayout flowManager = new FlowLayout(); area.setLayout(flowManager);`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Im using Java in easy steps, and it completely fails to mention the need to change the layout manager. Jeez. Thanks for saving the day  LuxxMiner

Comment: @KyleHarris `area`s layout was already `BorderLayout` before you changed it